# $\int_C\frac{z}{z^2+1}\,dz$ where $C:\ \{z:\ |z-0|=2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I used partial fraction decomposition and wrote
$$\int_C\frac{z}{z^2+1}\,dz=\frac12\int_c\frac{1}{z+i}\,dz+\frac12\int_C\frac{1}{z-i}\,dz$$
Here is an image for $C$.

[image]

Using the Extended Cauchy-Goursat Theorem, I wrote

$$
\begin{align}
\int_C\frac{z}{z^2+1}\,dz&=\frac12\int_{C_1}\frac{dz}{z+i}+\frac12\int_{C_2}\frac{dz}{z+i}+\frac12\int_{C_1}\frac{dz}{z-i}+\frac12\int_{C_2}\frac{dz}{z-i}\\[6pt]
\int_C\frac{z}{z^2+1}\,dz&=\frac12(0)+\frac12(2\pi\,i)+\frac12(2\pi\,i)+\frac12(0)\\[6pt]
\int_C\frac{z}{z^2+1}\,dz&=2\pi\,i
\end{align}
$$

Next, I tried to use a parametrization of the circle, 
$$z(t)=2e^{it}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad z'(t)\,dt=2ie^{it}\,dt\qquad\text{where}\qquad-\pi\le t\le \pi$$

Substituting these, I get:
$$
\begin{array}{tcl}
\int_C\dfrac{z}{z^2+1}\,dz&=&\int_{-\pi}^\pi\dfrac{2e^{it}}{(2e^{it})^2+1}(2ie^{it}\,dt)\\
\int_C\dfrac{z}{z^2+1}\,dz&=&\int_{-\pi}^\pi\dfrac{4ie^{i2t}}{4e^{i2t}+1}\,dt\\
\int_C\dfrac{z}{z^2+1}\,dz&=&\dfrac12\int_{-\pi}^\pi\dfrac{8ie^{i2t}\,dt}{4e^{i2t}+1}\,dt
\end{array}
$$

Now, I used 
$$u=4e^{i2t}+1\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad du=8ie^{i2t}\,dt$$
Note that
$$t=-\pi\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad u=4e^{i2(-\pi)}+1=4(1)+1=5$$
Similarly, $t=\pi\rightarrow u=5$. Now, the integral becomes
$$\frac12\int_5^5\frac{du}{u}$$
Now, I think this might equal zero, which is a different answer. What have I done wrong or what law am I disobeying?

Here is what Matlab returns.

```
syms z
clear f
f(z)=z/(z^2+1)
syms t real
z(t)=2*exp(i*t);
int(f(z(t))*diff(z(t),t),t,-pi,pi)
```

Ans:

$2\pi i$

**Update**  Thanks to Pythagoras, I think I understand what is happening. Here is some Matlab code that demonstrates his statement that arg increases by $4\pi$.

```
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
z=4*exp(i*2*t)+1; u=real(z); v=imag(z);
plot(z,'Color','b')
axis equal,axis([-4,6,-5,5])
grid on
ax=gca; ax.XAxisLocation='origin'; ax.YAxisLocation='origin';
hold on
n=length(t);
for k=1:n
    h=quiver(0,0,u(k),v(k),0,'Color','r','LineWidth',1);
    pause(0.1);
    delete(h)
end
quiver(0,0,5,0,0,'Color','r','LineWidth',1);
```

Comment: typo in the integral bounds*

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC No, the bounds seem correct. See my edits above to make it more clear.

Comment: "Similarly, $t=2\pi\rightarrow u=5$. Now, the integral becomes
$$\frac12\int_5^5\frac{du}{u}$$" This section.

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC $t=2\pi$ implies that $u=4e^{i2\pi}+1=4(1)+1=5$.

Comment: When you do substitution, the mapping shall be $1$-$1$ correspondence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you meant $t=-\pi$ and $t=\pi$, not $t=-2\pi$, etc. When $t$ goes through a period of $2\pi$, as you can check $u$ wraps around $0$ twice, so $\arg u$ changes by $4\pi$. Note that $\int \frac 1 u~du$ is not single valued; in general it is given by $\ln |u|+i\arg u$, so by the above remark $$\frac 12\int \frac 1u~du=\frac 12\cdot 4\pi i=2\pi i.$$

Comment: Thanks. Interesting answer. I fixed my typos and added some Matlab code that demonstrates your claim that the argument of $u$ increases by $4\pi$.